# target server does not expose service

Tags: grpc-java

I'm building a grpc Server in java and added a few services as shown below. I ran a debugger which showed that all the services seem to be there in the server object, yet when I make a grpcurl request, one of the services (`pkServiceRefactored`) doesn't respond to my query. The other services work fine and I don't know why only one fails to work

```java
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port).addService(pnlGRPCService).addService(pnlGRPCServiceRefactored)
                .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
                .addService(pkService).addService(pkServiceRefactored).build();
```

Comment: What's do you mean by not response to your query? Does it just hang or return some error?

Comment: It might be timed-out, error. However, we need more context(e.g. code) to find the root cause.